# Codeigniter extending system library doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I use Codeigniter 2.1.3 and trying to extend system library Cart:

I created My_Cart.php and put it in application/libraries/

It has:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // allow anything in the product name
        $this->product_name_rules = '\d\D';
    }


    // get in stock amount for every item in cart
    function enrich_stock()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

But when I use it in controller like `$this->cart->enrich_stock()`
I get error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Cart::enrich_stock() in .../application/controllers/cart.php on line 15**

The problem is that it is implemented totally as described in docs:
[Extending Native Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

and moreover it works fine on local server, but today I uploaded the whole site on production server, and the error appeared.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to rename the file to `MY_Cart.php`?  (Wild guess : If you happen to use Windows locally and Linux remotely.  It might work locally as Windows is case insensitive and Linux is case sensitive.  I had something similar happen to me already. )

Comment: Thanks a lot!! While writing here My_Cart I was actually looking at it as MY_Cart)) So, yes, the problem was in case sensitive Linux compared to Windows. thx

Comment: +1 to Maxime, capitalization is very important. My_Cart.php and MY_Cart.php are treated as distinct files in Linux environments. Also, Mac HFS+ filesystems commonly share Windows' case-insensitivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments, the solution is to rename `My_Cart.php` to `MY_Cart.php`.  The capitalization is important when using a system that is case sensitive such as Linux.

Comment: I posted the answer so this question does not pop in the unanswered list.